# Time between first draft of manuscript and submission

Tags: publications, collaboration

I drafted a manuscript at the end of August. Most coauthors and the corresponding authors have reviewed it. It is almost finished but not submitted yet. It is a bit frustrating. I wanted to ask if it is normal that there can be a delay between first draft and submission.

With my experience, it really depends. When we are 2 or 3 authors only, it is relatively quick. However, when we are more than 5 authors, the process of correcting a manuscript can take many months. Coauthors have to provide their input and may have different opinions on potential experiments to repeat or additional work to do.

So, did you also have to wait months for a paper to be submitted after having written it?

Comment: You're right.  It really, *really* depends.  In my own experience, the time between a first complete draft and final submission can vary from hours to years.

Comment: As it's stated (a question about personal experience, which varies), I don't see how this is an appropriate question for our site, or actually useful (i.e., actionable) for you?  Maybe a question like: what can you do to speed things up is better?

Comment: @Buzz +1 but hours sounds super fast to me (pure math)---even for solo papers, I'm not sure I've ever made it less than weeks for time from first draft to submission.

Comment: @Kimbal Yes, maybe it would be better to ask how we can speed up. Or maybe adk what is the most advantageous. Waiting to publish in top journals or speed up and publish in average impact journal.